# what mechanisms used by Whatsapp and Viber for Chatting and messaging

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, voip

I am searching some thing about Whatsapp and Viber.

They are providing Free calls ans SMS and Chatting functionality over VOIP.

Can any one identify what kind of Mechanisms are used by both application .

Means For Chat what kind of protocols are used and other details. and any other code which may be usefull to create chat applications like these.

please provide some details.

Comment: @V.VI am facing the same problem. I need to create a Chatting Box app, can you pls guide me for sol or refer me some sample links..Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whatsapp uses a custom XMPP server, Viber uses their own SIP voip server.

There are some opensource libraries for [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).

Comment: hey thanks for this information. Can you please provide some more details ??

Comment: No, I'm sorry never worked with the XMPP library for Objective-c.

Comment: @rckoenes, could you link your sources?

Comment: @Tom No I can't I just dit some packet sniffing.