# How to integrate Viber in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, viber

In one of my application I want to integrate Viber. I searched on google for SDK but all my effort went in vain. So I have following question.

**QUE:**

Is it possible to integrate Viber in my application?

If yes, then provide me link for SDK and doc.

**PURPOSE:**

In my application I want to implement invite feature. When user tap on "**Invite Via Viber**" my application will open vibe application. After that end-user will select the contact and in share predefined text that I Passed through my app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107172/what-mechanisms-used-by-whatsapp-and-viber-for-chatting-and-messaging

Comment: @iPatel Im looking for the SDK for Viber. So, that I can open Viber application and share link from my own app via custom URL Schema.

Comment: Can you give me proper reason to downward my question?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by Integrating viber? Explain the purpose..

Comment: @Akshit Zaveri I edited my question. Please recheck that.

Comment: Not really a question - more like a list of requirements.

Comment: @Abizern I edited my question. Please recheck that. Actually I did google but I did not found anything regarding SDK or DOCs. So first I want to know whether is it possible to achieve or not. If yes then how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do this. `Viber` does not provide any `SDK` or `API` for this purpose. You may take interest in login via **Facebook** or **Twitter**..

Because these social sites are way too popular than Viber.

You may look at these links:

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/
2. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios‎

Comment: I already implemented FB and Twitter and looking for more networks. But, its my bad luck that Viber is not providing and SDK for that. What about LINE?

Comment: Not possible @milanpanchal

Comment: Thanks...Also if you feel my question was relevant then Upvote that.

Comment: And if u felt my answer was helpful then mark it as correct.

Comment: Whoever downvoted it please explain my weakness in the answer. It was helpful to the asker of the question. Then why it's downvoted?

Comment: You can start the Viber application from within another application, but I haven't found a way to specify that it will open a specific contact.

I was able to identify the CFBundleURLSchemes from the Info.plist file (fb192454074134796), having downloaded the ipa in itunes and then opening in finder and unzipping.  Can then open the app from within my application by calling:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"url":@"fb192454074134796://"]

Comment: @NicholasHarlen that's not what asker needs.